# What are all of the sword levels and points requirements?

Tags: swap-sword

Bottom right, awarded on completion.

[image: Title screen]

Answer (score -1):

I'll collect sword names and point ranges here...

- Banana: ~0 - 300 pts.
- Wood (?): ?
- ?: ~800 - 900 pts.
- Quality: ~1000 pts.
- ?

[image]

[image]